# Does the next word after a colon have to be capitalized?

Tags: punctuation

If I write this line in a story:

She said: when are you going?

Does the "when" have to be capitalized?  Also, if the "she said" part is not part of a conversation in a novel does the word after the colon have to be capitalized?

*Additional info from OP's comment:*
I know English uses a comma after "said". I just use a colon for some avant-garde writing. What I am curious about is the capitalization of "when" if a colon is used in whatever context.

Comment: The moderators at [graphicdesign.se] have expressed interest in answering questions about typography.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about style and preference and general reference. It doesn't belong here.

Comment: I agree with Nathaniel that the question is essentially a duplicate of the one he identifies, but I disagree with the assertion that style questions about punctuation and capitalization are off-topic at EL&U. In my opinion they are very much on-topic as matters of (written) English usage.

Answer (score 2):

As Trevor said in his answer, this is not the standard way to punctuate a quotation.

There are, however, contexts where the punctuation construct you've described *would* be used. For example:

> There are three issues here: grammar, capitalization, and punctuation.

In cases like that, do we capitalize the word after the colon? Here's the short answer: It depends. [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/colon-grammar.aspx) says:

> it's a style choice, and it depends on what is following the colon

[Another style guide](http://www.jolenemorris.com/forstudents/APA6_QRC.pdf) reads:

> Capitalize first word after a colon if the expression after the colon is a complete sentence.

So, you could write:

> That's when the teacher asked me this question: "When are you going?"

That would mirror what the [Purdue OWL](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/index.php?category_id=2&sub_category_id=1&article_id=44) says:

> Use a colon after an independent clause when introducing a quotation.
>
> > *My teacher’s remark on my final essay was very complimentary: “This essay coherently analyzes musical trends of the late 20th century.”*

Comment: The [O’Reilly Style Guide](http://oreilly.com/oreilly/author/stylesheet.html#punctuation) states “Lowercase the first letter after a colon: this is how we do it. (Exception: headings.)” The heading exceptions refer to “headline casing” rules which may apply at a sufficiently high head level.

Comment: On the other hand, the house style at the computer magazines where I used to work was to initial-cap the first word after a colon if it could function as a complete sentence (as opposed to being, say, the first product in what was essentially a series or list of product names.

Answer (score 1):

1. English does not use a colon in that position. It uses a comma.
2. The spoken words should be within quotation marks.
3. The quotation itself should be punctuated and written independently of the containing sentence.

Thus:

> She said, "When are you going?"

**Addendum** (following OP's comment)

Even for some "avant-garde writing", I would follow my point 3 above: if the quotation is a complete sentence, then punctuate and capitalise it as such. I would, however, go further, ans suggest that,; but even if the quotation were not a single sentence because the speaker only spoke a partial sentence, or even only a single word, I would still capitalise and punctuate it *as if it were a full sentence*, thus indicating that that it is the full text of what was said.

However, if you are asking about using a colon in normal writing (and not in the context of a stylised form of quoting speech), then, no, you capitalise as you would in any continuation of a sentence, namely, only for a proper noun. For example, see:

- the first paragraph of this Addendum.
- the first indented paragraph of the answer from @J.R.

Comment: Verve, you may be thinking of scripts. In some scripts, dialog is written like this:

DARTH VADER: He will come to me?

THE EMPORER: I have foreseen it. His compassion for you will be his undoing. He will come to you and then you will bring him before me.

DARTH VADER: As you wish.

Arrgh, I forgot I can't show it properly in comments. It would be lined up differently, but the character name followed by a colon and then dialog is used.

But is you're writing a screenplay, don't do that.  Look up the format. Character name in the middle of the page in all caps, no colon, dialog below.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something different.  I know English uses a comma after "said".  I just use a colon for some avant-garde writing. :-)   What I was curious about was the capitalization of "when" if a colon is used in whatever context.

Comment: As regards your first sentence, your question did say "in a story". It helps if you provide as much info as appropriate so we understand your question fully. As regards your second sentence, it's still unclear whether you're still meaning when preceding a quotation in "avant-garde" style, or in any context in mid-sentence. See my amended answer. (I've also amended your question to include the additional info.)

Comment: I could easily find authorities that allow a colon (or neither colon nor comma) between a quote verb and the quote. (Though I'd often opt for the comma.)

Answer (score 1):

Legal transcription uses a colon after the question posed by the speaking attorney rather than a comma in most instances, and as long as what follows is a complete sentence, it is capitalized.  This would be considered formal transcription. Example:
Q.  Here's what I'm trying to find out: Did you see the car approach before it hit you?
Q.  Let me ask you this:  Did the truck hit the median first?